# Azure Devops Rest API - how to get all the projects for an organization - bypassing the authentication for the user

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

​Hello,

I want to access all the projects under an organization via Azure DevOps API. I have generated the PAT token using my account, but for my account I have access only to limited projects. Ideally via the API when I send a request to list all the projects, all the projects under the organization should be returned (bypassing the user authentication).

We are looking into creating a service account with admin access, but in that case - by using the service account I should not be able to login to Azure Devops.

Using this Azure DevOps API - https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects?api-version=5.1

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to by pass the authentication. You should have a PAT which has the permission to access all the projects.

You should ask your organization admin or any other accounts that have all projects access permission to generate a PAT for you. Then to call API with this PAT in your account.